# Bash string variable won't pass value

Tags: bash

If the last pipe is removed, it seems the value will pass and things will work until the connection is no longer active. Then the value then goes empty or null with a double quote still there. The sed command can strip that but the pipe won't let the value afterwards be passed. I'm stuck.

```
iwgetid wlan0 | grep 'ESSID:' | cut -c 18-24 | wtf=$(echo "$1"  

[[ -z "$1" ]] && echo -e "Wi-Fi Not Connected!" || echo -e "Connected"
```

Comment: See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

Comment: How do you think the output from `cut` is going to get into `$1` there, by the way? It doesn't, and can't; `$1` holds positional parameters, not content from stdin _or_ from the last command run.

Comment: BTW, next time you ask a question, you might think about creating a minimal reproducer -- something people could run to see your bug even if they don't, for instance, happen to be on a Linux machine using a wireless networking with a compatible version of `iwgetid`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything on the right-hand side of a pipeline is run in a subshell, meaning that assignments done there aren't visible anywhere else in your shell.

Also, where you get `$1` from is unclear here -- the values from `wtf` aren't getting into the positional arguments by anything you're doing. Fixing that:

```
wtf=$(iwgetid wlan0 | grep 'ESSID:' | cut -c 18-24 | sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//')
[[ -z "$wtf" ]] && echo -e "Wi-Fi Not Connected!" || echo -e "Connected"
[[ ! -z "$wtf" ]] && echo -e "Connected" || echo -e "Wi-Fi Not Connected!"
```

...that said -- this is really awful code. Readers, please don't consider places where I'm quoting from the OP as condoning same. :)